# Show there exists a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the cross sections are open subsets but $E \notin \mathcal{B}_2$.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, product-measure

> Show there exists a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the cross sections $[E]_a$ and $[E]^a$ are  open subsets for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ but $E \notin \mathcal{B}_2$.

This is a question from [Axler's book](https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf) on pg 144, exercise 2 and $\mathcal{B}_2$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that in general, <s>if a set $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, the cross sections aren't generally open</s> that if the cross sections are open, then it isn't necessarily true that the set itself is open.

The condition that $E$ can't be in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is really bothering me. I also thought maybe trying to use the Cantor function generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$, but didn't see immediately how to keep cross sections as open subsets.

Comment: Correction to a statement in the question: If $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$, then the cross sections $[E]_a$ and $[E]^a$ are indeed open subsets of $\mathbf{R}$ for every $a \in \mathbf{R}$. Here $$[E]_a =  \{ y \in \mathbf{R}: (a, y) \in E\}$$ and  $$[E]^a =  \{ x \in \mathbf{R}: (x, a) \in E\}.$$

Comment: Oops I meant to say that the converse of that statement isn't true in general. I made an edit to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb R$.  Then
$$
E = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(x,x): x \in A\}
$$
is your set.  It is not Borel.  But all the cross-sections are either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R$ minus a single point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Such a set exists as we can construct a subset of $[0, 1]$ which doesn't follow the additivity of outer measure; moreover, we know that the outer measure is a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$.

Let
\begin{equation}
E:=\{(x, x)\,|\,x\in A\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2
\end{equation}
Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then we observe
\begin{equation}
[E]_a=
\begin{cases}
    \{a\} & \text{if } a\in A, \\
    \,\phi & \text{if } a \not\in A.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Similarly, we get
\begin{equation}
[E]^a=
\begin{cases}
    \{a\} & \text{if } a\in A, \\
    \,\phi & \text{if } a \not\in A.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Thus, both the sets $[E]_a$ and $[E]^a$ are Borel sets.

Suppose $E\in \mathcal{B}\otimes \mathcal{B}$, then we have that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}\,|\,(x, x)\in E\}\in \mathcal{B}$ ([Refer this stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206505/prove-that-if-e-in-mathcals-otimes-mathcals-then-x-in-x-x-x-in)). But, observe that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}\,|\,(x, x)\in E\}=A$, which is not a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. This is a contradiction. Hence, $E\not\in\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{B}$.

Hence, $E$ is our required set.