# Prove that if $E \in \mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{S}$ then $\{x\in X: (x,x) \in E\} \in \mathcal{S}$

Tags: measure-theory

Problem: Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space. Prove that if $E \in \mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{S}$, then $\{x \in X: (x,x) \in E\} \in \mathcal{S}$

I know that for any $E \in \mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{S}$, $[E]_a$ and $[E]^b \in \mathcal{S}$, for any $a, b \in E$.  So, by setting $a=b$, we get that $([E]_a \cap [E]^a) \otimes ([E]_a \cap [E]^a)=\{(a,a)\} \in \mathcal{S}$. Now, when $E=X$, we have that $\{(x,x)\}\in \mathcal{S}\otimes \mathcal{S}$, $\forall x \in X$.

However, I cannot grasp how to proceed anywhere from this towards a solution to the given problem. Any hint/solution is welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection of all sets $E \in \mathcal S\otimes \mathcal S$ such that $\{x: (x,x) \in E\}$ belongs to  $\mathcal S$  is a $\sigma-$ algebra which contains sets of the type $E=A\times B$ where $A$ and $B$ belong to $\mathcal S$. Hence this class contains $S\otimes \mathcal S$ and this is what we are asked to prove. [This is the idea of the proof. Details are very straightforward].